# Регулярное выражение для чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка `^([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$`, как сделать чтобы она пропускала числа с плавающей точкой и запятой?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Примечание**. Все перечисленные ниже выражения предназначены для валидации целой строки. Если необходимо найти совпадения в тексте, удалите `^` и `$`.

**Ответ**

Замените `\.` на `[.,]` и уберите лишние скобки:

```js
^[0-9]*[.,][0-9]+$
```

Чтобы пропускала целые числа, добавьте квантификатор `?`:

```js
^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$
           ^
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/kjGNuw/1)

- `^` - начало строки
- `[0-9]*` - 0 и более цифр
- `[.,]` - точка или запятая (`[,.]?` - одна или ноль запятых или точек)
- `[0-9]+`  - 1 и более цифр
- `$` - конец строки.

Если нужно более "продвинутое" выражение, можно воспользоваться

```js
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,][0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

или - чтобы поддерживало и целые, и дробные числа:

```js
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Это вариант выражения на [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 4):

Для чисел с плавающей точкой есть несколько записей. Если вы подразумиваете наличие одной точки или запятой, то можно так:

```
^\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?$
```

[0-9]* -  вашем случае пропустит невалидную конструкцию , например **.5656**

Comment: почему она невалидна? Большинство  языков её понимают.

Comment: я про конкретный случай.
[0-9]* значит 0 и больше, то есть ,345345 пропустит
[0-9]+ значит 1 и больше

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)([.,]\d+)?
```

разрешает целые, дробные, исключает вариант с несколькими нулями перед дробной частью, на подобии: "000.0001".

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта регулярка

```
/^-?(0|[1-9]+)(?:[.,]\d{1,2}|)$/
```

разрешает целые и дробные числа, не пропускает записи вроде ".12" или "000.00", "0.11.11", также разрешает отрицательные и положительные. Чтобы изменить число знаков после запятой достаточно в части "{1,2}" изменить число "2" на нужное количество